# Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell while extracting the data from Excel

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, apache-poi

I'm trying to import data from Excel file to automate a large amount of data but I got the error "Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell" as some of the cells has a numeric values and others has a text value.I need to extract all data and insert it as inputs for the page fields. i got the error stating from

```
`package com.Demo;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class SignupformTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\VIRAL FISSION\\Music\\Selenium\\New folder\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",new String[] {"enable-automation"});
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
//        options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://app.viralfission.com/signup");
        
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\VIRAL FISSION\\Pictures\\testintakedata.xlsx");
        
     // Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
     XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    
     // Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
     XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
     
     
     int noofcount = sheet.getLastRowNum();
     
     System.out.print("No. of Records in the Excel sheet : " + noofcount);
     
     for(int row = 1; row <= noofcount; row++) {
         XSSFRow currentrow =  sheet.getRow(row);
         DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
         String cellvalue = formatter.formatCellValue(1,0);

         
         String Referal_Code = currentrow.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
         String First_Name = currentrow.getCell(1).getStringCellValue(); 
         String Last_Name = currentrow.getCell(2).getStringCellValue(); 
         String Contact_Number = currentrow.getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
         String WhatsApp_Number = currentrow.getCell(4).getStringCellValue(); 
         String Gender = currentrow.getCell(5).getStringCellValue(); 
         String Date_of_Birth = currentrow.getCell(6).getStringCellValue(); 
         String Flat_No = currentrow.getCell(7).getStringCellValue(); 
         String Building_Name = currentrow.getCell(8).getStringCellValue(); 
         String Street_Name = currentrow.getCell(9).getStringCellValue(); 
         String Landmark = currentrow.getCell(10).getStringCellValue(); 
         String State = currentrow.getCell(11).getStringCellValue(); 
         String City = currentrow.getCell(12).getStringCellValue(); 
         String Pincode = currentrow.getCell(13).getStringCellValue(); 
         String Instagram = currentrow.getCell(14).getStringCellValue(); 
         String Twitter = currentrow.getCell(15).getStringCellValue(); 
         
         
//       driver.findElement(By.linkText("https://app.viralfission.com/signup")).click();
         
         driver.findElement(By.name("referral")).sendKeys(Referal_Code);
         driver.findElement(By.name("firstname")).sendKeys(First_Name);
         driver.findElement(By.name("lastname")).sendKeys(Last_Name);
         driver.findElement(By.name("contactNumber")).sendKeys(Contact_Number);
         driver.findElement(By.name("whatsAppNumber")).sendKeys(WhatsApp_Number);
         
         
         Select dropgender = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("gender")));
         dropgender.selectByVisibleText(Gender);
         Select dropdateofbirth = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("DOB")));
         dropdateofbirth.selectByVisibleText(Date_of_Birth);
         
         driver.findElement(By.name("flatNumber")).sendKeys(Flat_No);
         driver.findElement(By.name("buildingName")).sendKeys(Building_Name);
         driver.findElement(By.name("streetName")).sendKeys(Street_Name);
         driver.findElement(By.name("landmark")).sendKeys(Landmark);
         
         
         Select dropState = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("state")));
         dropState.selectByVisibleText(State);
         Select dropCity = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("city")));
         dropCity.selectByVisibleText(City);
         
         driver.findElement(By.name("pincode")).sendKeys(Pincode);
         driver.findElement(By.name("instagram")).sendKeys(Instagram);
         driver.findElement(By.name("twitter")).sendKeys(Twitter);
         
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"cdk-step-content-0-0\"]/form/div[7]/button")).click();
        
        if(driver.getPageSource().contains("'Enter your details to get one step closer'")) {
            System.out.println("Good" + row + "Record");
        }

         
     }
     driver.close();


    }

}
`
```

**Can you please help me to sort out this, Why am getting this error? I have declared 9 Columns and 16 Rows using for loop. But am getting cannot Get The error as cannot get the string value from Numeic Cell.**

Comment: Use `DataFormatter` to turn all the cells into Strings as shown in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

```
FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = new XSSFFormulaEvaluator(book);
Cell cell = row.getCell(column);
if( CellType.FORMULA.equals(cell.getCellType())){
    return formulaEvaluator.evaluate(cell).formatAsString();
}else if( CellType.NUMERIC.equals(cell.getCellType())){
    return new BigDecimal(cell.getNumericCellValue()).toPlainString();
} else {
    return cell.getStringCellValue();
}
```